# Google speech API immediate timeout

Tags: swift, google-speech-api

I am building a swift app that uses the google speech api. Google speech was working an hour ago, but when I tried to run it again, the API immediately times out regardless of what timeout is set to. I have currently set the timeout to be 60 seconds however times out immediately. The error i get is:

```
GSpeechApiGRPC: Streaming audio data completion: (null), error: Error Domain=io.grpc Code=12 "GRPC target method can't be resolved." UserInfo={io.grpc.HeadersKey={
"alt-svc" = "hq=\":443\"; ma=2592000; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303338; quic=51303337; quic=51303335,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"41,39,38,37,35\"";
date = "Thu, 21 Dec 2017 21:49:35 GMT";
}, NSLocalizedDescription=GRPC target method can't be resolved., io.grpc.TrailersKey={
}}, done: 1
2017-12-21 21:49:35.087286+0000[5499:174593] GSpeechApiGRPC: Recognize failed: Error Domain=io.grpc Code=12 "GRPC target method can't be resolved." UserInfo={io.grpc.HeadersKey={
"alt-svc" = "hq=\":443\"; ma=2592000; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303338; quic=51303337; quic=51303335,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"41,39,38,37,35\"";
date = "Thu, 21 Dec 2017 21:49:35 GMT";
}, NSLocalizedDescription=GRPC target method can't be resolved., 
io.grpc.TrailersKey={
}}
```

I am using COCOAPODS. In the podfile, I am using "pod 'googleapis', :path => '.'"
In the pod file, looks like it fetched v1beta1 but same podfile in the google example fetched v1, this might be an issue

Comment: Possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47933071/grpc-target-method-cant-be-resolved

Comment: You could use Apple Speech Framework for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - the v1beta1 endpoint for the Cloud Speech API has been deprecated since April, and [is being turned down](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/cloud-speech-discuss/v1beta1%7Csort:date/cloud-speech-discuss/p8ZTlAVXyo0/7bbNoartCwAJ). You should migrate your code to using the stable v1 endpoint. It sounds like there's a pod you can switch to to do that? It shouldn't be too bad a transition - mostly you should just see a couple renames, and those should be stable now that it's out of beta.