# Python Google Speech v1 voice_activity_timeouts error

Tags: google-api, google-api-python-client, google-speech-api, google-speech-to-text-api

I am trying to use Google Speech v1 setting voice activity timeout but it got this error

`499 The operation was cancelled`

although I don't ask for any cancellation.

A similar questions were asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54908561/audio-timeout-error-in-speech-to-text-api-of-google-cloud), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76502806/python-google-speech-to-text-timeout-operation-was-cancelled) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47933728/google-speech-api-immediate-timeout) but they are very old or with no proper answer.

Thanks!

I'd like to properly set the timeout option declared in the google Python API documentation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.